# How to access spider name within settings.py in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I want to save all download images of a crawl in a specific folder, so I can run multiple spiders within the same project at the same time without having all images of multiple crawlw in one folder.

The img folder destination is defined within settings:

```
project_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/../' #<-- absolute dir the script is in
IMAGES_STORE = project_dir+"images"
```

My spider has a class like this within spidername.py:

```
class GetbidSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test_spider'
```

My image pipeline looks like this:

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

How can I access the name of the current spider within settings in order to create a dynamic image download folder?

Comment: have your spider class hold the path it is working on and access it that way
`spider.path = IMAGES_STORE+self.name` or something like that, then save the images to self.path

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `IMAGES_STORE` value per spider instead? Look at the example in the documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider

Comment: If you instantiate 2 spiders with a default override setting then you need a way to dynamically customize the setting, but that would be a good start, seeing as it is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to override the `ImagesPipeline`, being more specific would be the `image_downloaded` method, so you can do whatever you want with what you got from the crawler.

Now, I assume you want to change that settings variable each time you run the spider, so you don't have to go around and change the settings each time before running it.

An alternative to change settings on each run, would be to pass it as a crawl argument:

```
scrapy crawl test_spider -s IMAGES_STORE=test_spider
```

Another way would be to set it on `custom_settings` for each spider in your code:

```
class GetbidSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test_spider'

    custom_settings = {
        'IMAGES_STORE': 'test_spider',
    }
```

and just run your spider normally:

```
scrapy crawl test_spider
```

Comment: Thank you, this workes, however I need to add quite a bit of code to each of the many spiders instead of  having a one code solution. 
Following your suggestion this looks like this:

    project_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/../../' #<-- absolute dir the script is in
    img_dir     = project_dir+"images/"+name
    if not os.path.exists(img_dir):
        os.mkdir(img_dir);
    custom_settings = {
        'IMAGES_STORE': img_dir ,
    }

Do you see another way to avoid such an amount of duplicated code?

Comment: my recommendation is to override `ImagesPipeline` then (my first comment on the answer), it should relatively simple.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I must admit I do now know how to do that, my imagepipeline has no such function (edited question) and I can not find such a method within the scrapy docs: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html